# Apache - how to limit maximum download speed of files? (if not apache, i can run lighthttpd)

Tags: apache, lighttpd

I have a bunch of videos but I only want to limit the maximum download speed for these files to be 1mbps. How can I set this up (ideally in Apache but lighthttpd is an option)

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to limit the download speed per connection, without any regard for managing the totals or performing more fine-grained controls, the best way to handle this is to use Apache's own `mod_ratelimit`.

This example restricts everything under `/files` to `1Mbit/s`...

```
<Location /files>
    SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
    SetEnv rate-limit 1000
</Location>
```

I've researched and tried other methods and modules, and in this specific case, mod_ratelimit is hands down the easiest way to do this.

[Download Speed Limit and Throttling for Apache 2.4](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/download-speed-limit-and-throttling-for-apache-2-4).

Comment: Actually, this example restricts to 1Mbyte/s.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [mod_bandwidth](http://www.cohprog.com/mod_bandwidth.html) or the more advanced [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/).

It appears the original site of [mod_cband](http://dembol.org/blog/mod_cband/) is offline.  GitHub user "maiha" set up an archive of the original at [mod_cband](https://github.com/maiha/mod_cband/).

Quote from mad_bandwidth site:

> `Mod_bandwidth` is a module for the Apache webserver that enable the
> setting of server-wide or per connection bandwidth limits, based on
> the directory, size of files and remote IP/domain.

Quote from `mod_cband` site:

> `mod_cband` is an Apache 2 module provided to solve the problem of
> limiting users’ and virtualhosts’ bandwidth usage. The current
> versions can set virtualhosts’ and users’ bandwidth quotas, maximal
> download speed (like in `mod_bandwidth`), requests-per-second speed and
> the maximal number of simultanous IP connections (like in
> `mod_limitipconn`)

Here is a tutorial about [how to use cband to limit download speed](http://blog.camilord.com/2012/06/13/manage-apache-download-speed-and-traffic-limits/).

Comment: thanks, ill look into that. do you know if theres anything on a per-connection basis? (I don't want to limit the whole vhosts entry or user to a maximum download speed, just the surfer on the website (each one having their own limit of say 1mbps))

Comment: It is not obvious how to distinguish between connections in order to limit only for some of them. Another solution: you can host bandwidth limited version under separate port and redirect to bandwidth limited version if user has limit of 1mbps from main website using website code.

Comment: cband is buggy. over throttled my server by a factor of 5 or 6