# How to get file download speed (transfer rate) with php?

Tags: php, file, download

I wanna to sum bandwidth of each user during download the file . I **use** php download and **resumable** or **limit speed** download . But i have a problem , i don't know to how find **download speed** or **transfer rate** of user when during download from my site .

Answer (score 0):

From the answer of [PHP Download file, limit max speed and calculate downloading speed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18546045/6521116), there is not a simple way to calculate the download speed by php. While to calculate the download speed on the client side it's easy, you can refer to [How to detect internet speed in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5529718/6521116). So you can ajax to polling the download speed to server, when the user downloading the file.